# Modify sqlite database through two releases of the same iPhone app

Tags: iphone, database, xcode, sqlite

some times ago I release my first iPhone app, with a simple SQLite database in it. After two months, I publish an upgrade of the app, and change some contents of the database (I add new entries); unfortunately the updated app always crashed: the only workaround was to delete and reinstall the app from the store. After that it was all ok.

My question is : is this a problem of the sqlite database? How can I modify my database in a updating of my app and avoid the deleting-reinstalling procedure?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I assume you use core data and you changed the schema in addition to adding some new rows. If you change the schema you need to follow a certain path (described in detail in core data docs) to be able to upgrade (without deleting and reinstalling). Basically you need to have both versions of the database and transfer between them manually.

Comment: No, I did not use CoreData, I modified the database at hand (and I did not change the schema, I only added new rows).